How to create a SQL query to run an incremental load for a table without datetime column by joining with another table
I have a derivative table without a timestamp column. I want to view the last 7 days updated data in the table.
I also have a parent table (foreign key: ID with the derivative table) which has a timestamp column.
How do I join both to get the incremental records for the derivative table in SQL?
I tried the given script however it resulted in an error
SELECT
    COM_PHYSICAL_PDF_BLOB.* 
FROM
    COM_PHYSICAL_PDF_BLOB cppb 
WHERE
    COM_PHYSICAL_FILE.UPDATE_DATE < 2023-02-07 07:30:02.000
INNER JOIN
    COM_PHYSICAL_FILE on COM_PHYSICAL_FILE.ID = COM_PHYSICAL_PDF_BLOB.ID


WHERE clauses usually come after JOIN. What error do you get when you run your statement?

question is extremely unclear. What comes from where. The syntax of the query, most probably is something like  select cppb .* from COM_PHYSICAL_PDF_BLOB cppb
inner join COM_PHYSICAL_FILE f on cppb.id=f.id
where f.UPDATE_DATE < '2023-02-07 07:30:02.000'

Please provide a [mre]

Not sure why this was closed as "does not appear to be about programming". Seems like a programming question to me - one related to joining two tables, applying a condition against one, and selecting from the other, as described by the OP. The issue turned out to be a syntax problem in the posted code, relating to the the order of join vs where clauses. Luckily, @BartMcEndree posted a helpful answer before the question was closed. SO need to stop knocking people down for not licking the floor properly as they approach the throne.

@TN actually it was closed because it doesn't meet stack overflow guidelines, which is this case means the 3 close votes where for a different reasons. Personally I VTC because the desired outcome was not clear.

@tanmay are you familywith accepting an answer? Because I note you haven't accepted a single answer to any of your questions.

@DaleK - I see what you mean about the close banner description. I just dropped a "duplicate" close vote on this question, but the close reason in the banner is "need details or clarity", with no mention or link to the candidate duplicate. (The auto-generated comment remains though.) I guess either majority or perhaps first vote cast prevails.

You need to correct the order of your WHERE vs JOIN clause and use consistent table aliasing
SELECT cppb.* 
FROM COM_PHYSICAL_PDF_BLOB cppb 
INNER JOIN COM_PHYSICAL_FILE cpf on cpf.ID = cppb.ID  
WHERE cpf.UPDATE_DATE < '2023-02-07 07:30:02.000'

fiddle
